# Calculate total measure in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help to create a measure that calculates totals in such a way that when I drag that measure to a table it is not affected by the filters of each row.

To explain it better, I'll give you an example. A company sells two products (tables and chairs) to two consumers:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZntaH.jpg

What I am looking for is a measure that would calculate the total for each product (8 chairs sold and 3 tables), regardless of the invoice or the customer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFXZ7.jpg

Note that each column in the visualization belongs to different tables (related to each other). Thank you very much!!

**UPDATE**. These are the tables I am really working with:

```
CountOfPurchasetimes3 = 
VAR TblSummary =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        fact_sale_invoice_line,
        fact_sale_invoice_line[product_id],
        fact_sale_invoice_line[customer_id]
    ),
    "TotalPurchase", 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT(fact_sale_invoice_line[product_id]),
        ALLEXCEPT(fact_sale_invoice_line,fact_sale_invoice_line[product_id],fact_sale_invoice_line[customer_id])
    )
)

VAR count_times =
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('fact_sale_invoice_line'[product_quantity])>0,
        AND(
            fact_sale_invoice_line[invoice_date_id]>=20220101,
            fact_sale_invoice_line[invoice_date_id]<=20220131
        )
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(TblSummary,[TotalPurchase]),
        AND(
            fact_sale_invoice_line[invoice_date_id]>=20220101,
            fact_sale_invoice_line[invoice_date_id]<=20220131
        )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
RETURN count_times
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 methods to achieve your result:

Method_1

```
total unit by product = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    VALUES(YourTbl[product]),
    "Total", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTbl[units by invoice]),ALL(YourTbl),VALUES(YourTbl[product]))
)
RETURN
    SUMX(TblSummary,[Total])
```

Method_2

```
total unit by product = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    VALUES(YourTbl[product]),
    "Total", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTbl[units by invoice]),ALLEXCEPT(YourTbl,YourTbl[product]))
)
RETURN
    SUMX(TblSummary,[Total])
```

[image: G1G1]

---

To calculate purchase quantity:

```
CountOfPurchasetimes = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(YourTbl,YourTbl[product],YourTbl[customer_id]),
    "TotalPurchase", CALCULATE(COUNT(YourTbl[product]),ALLEXCEPT(YourTbl,YourTbl[product],YourTbl[customer_id]))
)
RETURN
    SUMX(TblSummary,[TotalPurchase])
```

and lets test it on the visual:

[image: DFGGG]

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry but also I need a measure that in each row puts the number of times a customer repeats the purchase of the same product. (Customer 1 buys 2 times the chairs and 1 time the tables; Customer 2 buys 1 time the chairs and 1 time the tables. 

In other words, the new column should be [2,1,1,1,2]. 

I have added the .pbix file to the end of the question in case it is more comfortable for you. Thank you again!

Comment: Check my post. I added your request.

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I try to calculate it for a certain period it does not recognize it. I don't understand why.  I've updated the post so you can see what I tried.

Comment: Because There is no such column [invoice_date_id] on your fact_sale_invoice_line table.

Comment: Nice to hear it! Good news! You're welcome!